# Best way to store variable length data in single column

Tags: json, presto, amazon-athena

I'm looking for some opinions on how to best store some data. I have some data that resembles the following:

```
id  category    proportion
1   1           0.99
1   7           0.85
2   1           0.55
3   2           0.90
3   3           0.85
```

Basically, unique ID's can belong to varying numbers of categories. Each id and category has a proportion associated with it.

I want to store this data in a single column so that I can add it to a table where each id may only inhabit a single row.

Right now, I've been contemplating two json structures. Consider the example of `id = 1`. We'd have something like the following two options...

1. Unnested: `{"category1": "1", "proportion1": "0.99", "category2": "7", "proportion2": "0.85"}`
2. Nested: `{"category1": {"label": "1", "proportion": "0.99"}, "category2": {"label": "7", "proportion": "0.85"}}`

I'm not too familiar with json in Presto/Athena. Use cases would include a) *looking up ids given a specific category label* or b) *grouping id attributes by individual category labels*.

For example, I may want to identify all id's that belong to category = 3. I don't think either of these structures would make this easy in Athena.

Looking for any feedback you may have. I do think the optimal structure is one row per id + category combination but that is not an option for this use case.

Comment: is there a reason you are putting this in json or wanting to restructure the data?  why not just keep it in the table format you have listed?  How much data is this?

Comment: I'd also leave it in the format above.  If you do decide to go down this path, it is important to note that JSON is really expensive to process.  It is just a text blob to the engine that must be parsed for each read.  Instead if you use a combination of structural types like ARRAY, MAP, or ROW, the engine can process the data directly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I've decided to take the approach of creating the table in the ideal format that I've mentioned and just added a reference in the other table that the user can use to lookup. I had a feeling that ARRAY, MAP, and ROW were more effective in Presto so it is good to have the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tabular format that you start out with is preferable to the JSON structures you suggest as alternatives. You can always use SQL to get other formats, so choosing the format that makes the fewest assumptions about access patterns, and looks the most like a table is usually best, unless you have very specific requirements – which it doesn't sound like you have.

In the end it also depends a lot on how you will be producing the data. The beauty of Athena is that it's pretty good at handling most structures that you can throw at it. Keep the data in the format that it is produced in and you can almost always use SQL to get the answer you need. If it turns out to be too slow or too expensive that way you can use Athena to convert the data into other formats and structures that are more suitable, but always keep the data in its original format too – that way you can always create even more versions for new situations.

If it's not too much data you can also use views to create optimised representations for different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Data modeling should be derived from queries access pattern as much as possible. But if you are not aware of all the patterns then there are few points to consider:

- Try to use denormalized table to avoid many joins
- Use Parquet/ORC file formats over JSON/CSV
- In your case Parquet could be better as you are looking for Nested data structure but make sure that you are not querying on those sub-fields of nested structure to avoid performance issues.

Here, you can store id and category as two separate columns so that query by id or category can be supported.

Athena is just a wrapper on top of Presto to provide server less SQL offering. Essentially data is stored in your s3 object storage and Presto processing engine will fetch the data every time before processing. You can also use Rubix for caching hot data to avoid s3 read every time.